# Considering a move back to EOS - a couple of questions

Tags: system-installation

Firstly, I am running an Intel NUC 11 with an Intel "on-board" GPU and a discrete GPU nVidia RX 2060.

I need to use the Intel for day to day, and the nVidia for gaming....can EOS 7 handle this (assuming correct nVidia and Intel drivers are installed) by allowing me to switch? I have read that some distros can "auto-sense" gaming and switch automatically, but that could just be "urban myth".

Subsequent question to the above - do the available (if any) drivers for both actually work in EOS? I did have an earlier experience in trying EOS and after install, everything was green???

Second question is how EOS handles LE Bluetooth devices...I have a Logitech MX Master 3 BT mouse which I am having a very difficult time in the current OS getting it to work, it doesn't. It's a minor thing but important nonetheless.

Finally, how is EOS in gaming, in particular, running with Steam games?

Thanks IA.